# Filter a flat, associative array by the keys in another flat, associative array

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, associative-array, array-intersect

I have two arrays:

`$arr1 = array('a' => 10, 'b' => 20);`

`$arr2 = array('a' => 10, 'b' => 20, 'c' => 30);`

How can I use `array_filter()` to drop elements from `$arr2` that don't exist in `$arr1`? Like "c" in my example.

Comment: In your example, you don't need to because you can just use `$arr1` instead: `$arr2 = $arr1;`. So probably you want to add some information what specifically is the point here.

Comment: This is not a terrific [mcve] because the sample data  has identical associative elements.  Your plain English description of the requirements may be not be accurately expressing your goal or may confuse readers who do not use English as a first language.  Changing the element value for, say, `b` in one of the arrays would help to crystalize what is desired in the result array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a function specifically made for this purpose: [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php):

> **array_intersect** — Computes the intersection of arrays

```
$arr2 = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);
```

---

If you want to compare keys, not the values like [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php), use [array_intersect_key()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php):

> **array_intersect_key** — Computes the intersection of arrays using keys for comparison

```
$arr2 = array_intersect_key($arr1, $arr2);
```

---

If you want to compare `key=>value` pairs, use [array_intersect_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php):

> **array_intersect_assoc** — Computes the intersection of arrays with additional index check

```
$arr2 = array_intersect_assoc($arr1, $arr2);
```

Comment: thanks, it works with array_intersect_key but only if I switch arguments

Comment: As an addition, for those who may want to compare keys but provide the keys as values, you can use array_flip as well, eg. `$arr2 = array_intersect_key($arr1, array_flip($arr2));`

Answer (score 4):

Use [in_array](http://php.net/in_array) in your array_filter callback:

```
$arr2 = array_filter($arr2, function($e) use ($arr1) {
    return in_array($e, $arr1);
  });
```

Note that this will regard the *values* of the elements, not the keys. array_filter will not give you any key to work with so if that is what you need a regular [foreach](http://php.net/foreach) loop may be better suited.

Answer (score 1):

To get the elements that exist in `$arr2` which also exist in `$arr1` (i.e. drop elements of `$arr2` that don't exist in `$arr1`), you can intersect based on the key like this:

```php
array_intersect_key($arr2, $arr1); // [a] => 10, [b] => 20
```

**Update**

Since PHP 7 it's possible to pass `mode` to `array_filter()` to indicate what value should be passed in the provided callback function:

```php
array_filter($arr2, function($key) use ($arr1) {
  return isset($arr1[$key]);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Since PHP 7.4 you can also drop the `use ()` syntax by using arrow functions:

```php
array_filter($arr2, fn($key) => isset($arr1[$key]), ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```