# Sorting an array by another array with duplicate values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've seen a few questions with similar topics, but most of them used `arrays` such as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` for sorting, as opposed to what I need to use, which is `[1, 1, 2, 1, 4]`, with the largest numbers coming first, and the zeroes removed.

Example:
`[4, 3, 8, 0, 0]` as the array to sort by, and `["hello", "my", "name", "is", "indigo"]` as the array to be sorted.
This should be turned into:
`["name", "hello", "my"]`
because the zeroes are removed.

My main issue is that most methods I've tried end up assigning the values in one array to the numbers in another. Example:

`[4, 1, 1, 4, 8]` and `["hello", "my", "name", "is", "indigo"]`

should return `["indigo", "is", "hello", "my", "name"]`, but returns `["indigo", "hello", "hello", "my", "my"]`, or something to that effect.

Comment: use php array **sort()** function

Comment: rsort() and array_filter() ?

Comment: try something on your own and let us know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [array\_filter based on keys from another array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894443/array-filter-based-on-keys-from-another-array)

Comment: The question editing is getting a bit out of hand so the answers look off topic now.

Comment: I've tried several things, but it seems like most people are misunderstanding my question. I'm asking how I would do this with one array as the values to sort by, and another as the values to be sorted.

Comment: @Satisfaction I noticed that people were misunderstanding the question, so I edited in order to clear up misunderstanding.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the original question

Comment: @william.eyidi What doesn't? This discussion?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this?

```
$words = array("hello", "my", "name", "is", "indigo");
$order = array(0, 1, 3, 2, 4);
$result = array_map(function($o) use ($words){
    return $words[$o];
}, $order);
```

Which produces this:

```
array(5) {
    [0] = string(5) "hello"
    [1] = string(2) "my"
    [2] = string(2) "is"
    [3] = string(4) "name"
    [4] = string(6) "indigo"
}
```

**Update**

I have reread your question but I am still unsure what you seek?
I have updated my original code, but now 0's are removed and it is ordered largest numbers to smallest. Although if the 0's are removed you cannot access the first element of the array?

If this is not correct, perhaps you could explain what it is doing wrong, and what it needs to be doing differently. I suspect the issue is just a language breakdown.

```
$words = array("hello", "my", "name", "is", "indigo");
$order = array(0, 0, 4, 4, 3, 1);

$order  = array_filter($order); // remove 0's
rsort($order);                  // Largest First
$result = array_map(function($o) use ($words){
    return $words[$o];
}, $order);
```

Which produces this:

```
array(4) {
    [0] = string(6) "indigo"
    [1] = string(6) "indigo"
    [2] = string(2) "is"
    [3] = string(2) "my"
}
```

Comment: This actually almost works, but it assigns things like `[0, 0, 4, 4]` + `["text1", "text2", "text3", "text4"]` as `["text1", "text1", "text3", "text3"]`

Comment: @Hate9 which is exactly what I thought you wanted? You will need to elaborate more if not.

Comment: My initial question was too vague, but I've edited it to make more sense since.

Comment: This is really difficult to explain.
So, what I meant with the zeroes is that if you had, say,
`$words = array("hello", "my", "name", "is", "indigo");`
`$order = array(0, 0, 4, 4, 3);`
then removing the zeroes would remove `"hello"` and `"my"` from `$words`.

I think I can do that, though. My main issue now is getting the `words` sorted by `order`, without simply assigning `words`' values to `order`'s locations on a new array.

Essentially, I would need the example I gave in this comment to return `["indigo", "name", "is"]` or `["indigo, "is", "name"]`.

Answer (score 0):

you want to use `rsort()`

**solution**

```
$arrayVariable = array(1, 1, 2, 1, 4);

rsort($arrayVariable);
```

here is the manual [rsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php)

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I've edited it to make it more understandable, but you'll probably want to remove this question.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I finally figured out what was wrong with what I was doing, and fixed it. For anyone who was curious as to what I was trying to do (since I was apparently shit at it), or how I eventually did it, here's my code:

```
$words=array("hello","my","name","is","indigo");
$sort=array(4,3,8,0,0);
$count=0;
foreach($sort as $item){
    if ($item==0) {
        $count++;
    }
}
$cut=count($sort)-$count;
for($i=count($sort); $i>=$cut; $i--) {
    unset($sort[$i]);
    unset($words[$i]);
}
array_multisort($sort,$words);
$words=array_reverse($words);
foreach($words as $word){
    echo $word."<br>";
}
```

Which outputs:

```
name
hello
my
```